# Where is the definition of a class stored in memory as opposed to the instance?

Tags: oop, memory-management

This question is merely out of interest and trying to understand something about memory management in object-oriented languages. It is not specific to one language, but I just want to understand as a general principle.

What I want to know is how the definition of an object reference is stored compared to the instance of that reference.

When you define and object in OO source code, e.g. in Java, without instantiating it:

```
String s;
```

How does this get stored? How does the memory usage of this definition differ from when the object is actually instantiated:

```
s = new String("abc");
```

? Is there a general principle that applies to all OO languages in terms of how memory is allocated or do different language implementers use different techniques for allocating memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normaly when we declare a refrence like **String s;** it is created as a normal variable just like int , float but this type of variable hold the memory address ( it similar concept as pointers in C language) but when we use  **s = new String("abc");**, it creates an object in heap and assign that address to the reference variable **s**.

Answer (score 0):

In Java byte code, all Objects are stored as Objects. Explicit type-checking is added when needed. So for example this Java function

```
public Integer getValue(Object number){
  int i = ((Number) number).toInt();
  return new Integer(i);
}
```

is translated to a bytecode like this:

```
(accepts java.lang.Object, returns java.lang.Integer)

-read the first argument as an Object
-if the value is not a Number, raise an exception
-call the virtual method toInt(java.lang.Integer) of the value
    and remember the int result
-use the value as an int argument
-instantiate a new java.lang.Integer
-call the constructor(int) of java.lang.Integer on the new number,
    getting an Object back
[since the declared return value of Number.toInt is the same
    as the return value of our function, no type checking is needed]
-return the value
```

So, types of unused variables get stripped out by the compiler. Types of public and protected fields are stored with its class.

The runtime type of an Object is stored with the object. In C++, it is a pointer to the Virtual Method Table. In Java, it is as a 16-bit index into the table of all loaded classes.

The Java class file stores an index of all dependent classes in a similar table. Only the class names are stored here. All field descriptions then point to this table.

So, when you write `String s = new String("abc")` (or even `String s = "abc"`), your class stores:

- it is dependent on the class java.lang.String in the table of dependencies
- "abc" in the table of String literals
- your method loading a String literal by ID
- (in the first case) your method calling a constructor of its first dependent class (String) with the first dependent class (String) as an argument.
- the compiler can prove storing the new String in a String variable is safe, so it skips the type checking.

A class can be loaded as soon as it is referenced, or as late as its first use (in which case it is refered to by its depending class and ID within the class). I think the latter is always the case nowadays.

When a class is loaded:

```
-its class loader is asked to retreive the class by its name.
-(in the case of the system loader) the class loader looks
    for the corresponding file in the program JAR, in the system library
    and in all libraries referenced.
-the byte stream is then decoded into a structure in memory
-(in the case of early loading) all dependent classes are loaded recursively
    if not already loaded
-it is stored in the class table
-(in the case of late loading) its static initialiser is run
    (possibly loading more classes in the process).
```

In C++, none of the class loading takes place, as all user classes and most libraries are stored in the program as a mere virtual method table and the corresponding method. All of the system functions (not classes) can still be stored in a DLL (in case of Windows) or a similar file and loaded by the library at runtime. If a type checking is implied by an explicit type-cast, it is performed on the virtual method table. Also note that C++ did not have a type checking mechanism for a while.